# Как вернуть удаленный файл в GIT

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-revert

Кто сможет помочь объяснить механику работы с `GIT`?

1. Допустим у нас есть ветка `master` c двумя файлами, c нее сделали копию ветку `dev`.
2. удалим один файл с ветки `master`, делаем `commit`
3. сделаем `merge` с ветки `dev` в `master` и разницы в ветках нет, `merge` не получается, несмотря на удаленный файл.

Вопрос:
Как правильно вернуть удаленный файл не откатывая `commit` в котором удалили файл на этапе 2?
Что делать, если файлов несколько, а в ветках есть и другие изменения, который нельзя откатить полностью?
Сэмулировал ситуацию в [репозитории](https://gitlab.com/teaguru/test)

Comment: `$ git checkout коммит-когда-файлы-ещё-были -- имя-файла1 имя-файла2 ...`

Comment: Тогда улетят другие правки, сделанные в томже мердже

Comment: не знаю, о чём вы говорите, но приведённая выше команда сделает ровно то, о чём у вас написано в вопросе: создаст указанные файлы в том виде, как они были зафиксированы в указанном коммите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если команде `checkout` передать список файлов, то она восстановит содержимое этих файлов в том виде, как они были зафиксированы в указанном коммите (если не указать ни хэш коммита, ни имя указателя — ветки или метки — то будет использован указатель `HEAD`).

на случай, если имя какого-нибудь из файлов совпадает с именем какого-нибудь указателя — метки или ветки — лучше отделить их от остальных аргументов с помощью `--`.

для описанной в вопросе ситуации команда будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$ git checkout коммит-когда-файлы-ещё-были -- имя-файла1 имя-файла2 ...
```

Comment: Хм.. У меня по сути такой же ответ, только про возможность указать несколько имён не вспомнил. А вот описание у нас разное)))

Comment: ну да, команда-то одна и та же для очень-очень разных действий. и описание к ней можно приложить разное. например, написать про какие-то «родственные ветки», или упомянуть непонятно зачем про опцию `--force`

Comment: Под родственными я имел в виду, что она не является мёрджем. А что с force не так? Это же чтобы незакоммиченные изменения перетереть (если файл не удалён, а изменён).

Comment: `--force` не требуется в таком случае.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я подобные правки делаю руками:

1. git checkout коммит-когда-файлы-ещё-были
2. Руками копирую файлы в какую-нибудь папку снаружи репозитория
3. git checkout master
4. Руками копирую файлы в репозиторий
5. git add . ; git commit -m '...'

Comment: Но можно проще.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы приделать к текущей ветки файлы из другой, можно находясь в ветке `master` выполнить

```
git checkout dev -- путь/к/файлу/или/папке
```

при этом текущая ветка останется, а соответствующие файлы возьмутся из указанной ветки. После этого их можно будет закоммитить, но ветки считаться родственными не будут.

Если есть необходимость перезаписать некие изменения, можно в команде выше использовать флаг `--force`.